# .htaccess image localhost

Tags: htaccess, html, images, server

So I've created simple .htaccess file as following to make my webiste more SEO:

```
# PROTECT FILES
<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|fla|psd|log|sh)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

#TURNED REWRITE ON
RewriteEngine on

#REWRITE CONDITIONS
RewriteRule start index.html
RewriteRule aboutMe about.html
RewriteRule contact contact.html
RewriteRule portfolio portfolio.php
RewriteRule reportage reportage.php
```

But the problem is that my images don't load properly. I used for them previously:

```
<?php 
   $files = glob("reportageImages/*.jpg");

   for($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++){
     $imageDir = $files[$i];
     echo '<li><img src="'.$imageDir.'" alt="reportage"/></li>';
   }
?>
```

or directly without php:

```
<img src="reportageImages/lama.jpg"/>
```

and the directory was xamp/htdocs/MG/reportageImages/(here .jpg file) as I'm using xaamp to test my project.

I'm quite mislead by similar questions asked, as for some problems really sounding as mine works simply `<base href="/" />`, unfotunately not for me.
So I would really appreciate any help from you guys, I'm missing sth and tutorials over Internet don't cover all the topics. What worry me also is if in some way I would come over it, would the solution differ if I moved from local server to hosting?

Added photo to better visualize path problems:
[image: filepath screenshot]

Photos are counted well in directory ( I do same operation for each one and got relevant numbers of broken images boxes).

Comment: What is the URL you are requesting? Where are your .htaccess, index.html, about.html, etc. files located? What is your document root? `xamp/htdocs` or `/xamp/htdocs/MG`? "don't load properly" - do you mean they don't load at all, ie. 404? You imply that it is only since implementing your .htaccess file that the images have stopped loading - but nothing in your .htaccess file should have changed this?

Comment: all: .htaccess, .html and .php files are in /MG as well as css folder and js. I have just alt printed instead of image and image broken icon.

Comment: And what image URL is the _browser_ requesting (check the network tab of the object inspector). Do the CSS and JS files load OK - what is the difference with these URLs? If your document root is `xamp/htdocs` then the `href` attribute of the `base` tag should be `/MG/` (or `/MG/start`), not `/` - however - it is not obvious from what you have posted why the relative path, with no `base` tag, is not working.

Comment: Failed to load resource:  file:///D:/xamp/htdocs/MG/'.$imageDir.', but, $imageDir with this php code should look like reportageImages/image.jpg, so still I don't know what's wrong ... :(
css and js files are ok, everything is properly placed and gallery slider is also right

Comment: It's really strange to me, as it properly sets number of items in gallery, but path to images are someway completely wrong. And i cannot even say why.

Comment: What is the value of the `src` attribute in the HTML (page source)? You certainly shouldn't be seeing `file:///D:/xamp/htdocs/` - that is as if you are trying to load a resource outside of your webserver, from the local filesystem?! Are you actually seeing the text `$imageDir` in the reported URL?!

Comment: w3dk is perfectly right. Your URL should be an http or https and not file. Your links are incorrect.

Comment: I added photo how it looks now, I must have sth messed up when I wrote about D: directory.

Comment: The URL in your screenshot looks OK (no mention of `file://...`?), but the image is broken. The URL in your screenshot looks OK - except that it states "portfolioImages" instead of "reportageImages" as mentioned in your question? Since the URL "looks" ok, a `base` element is not going to help. Does the network traffic still show `file://...`? You've not answered the question in my first comment... has this problem only started since adding the .htaccess file? If you remove the .htaccess file, do the images load? Do you have any other .htaccess files anywhere else along the directory path?

Comment: before adding .htaccess everything works great, but ofcourse my href's were sth link "portfolio.php" and "reportage.php" instead of reportage and "portfolio"/"reportage" which I stated in RewriteRule(s). I have not more .htaccess files. Now I haven't that error which you suggest me to check in Network object inspector.

Comment: w3dk Ty for your effort, shame on me. I should solve it faster and not take your priceless time. Sorry and thanks once again, you keep me on trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `RewriteRule portfolio portfolio.php`
>   `RewriteRule reportage reportage.php`

Sorry, just realised what's going on... you need to be more *specific* in your rewrites. The above rules will rewrite the URL if "portfolio" (or "reportage") appear *anywhere* in the requested URL - this will catch your image URLs as well (since "portfolio" and "reportage" are part of the URL *path*), and that's the problem. (I would expect this to also generate a rewrite loop - which would also result in a broken image. In this case the server's error log should give clues as to the "rewrite loop".)

Make your rules more specific, to match only the URL in the request. For example:

```
#REWRITE CONDITIONS
RewriteRule ^start$ index.html [L]
RewriteRule ^aboutMe$ about.html [L]
RewriteRule ^contact$ contact.html [L]
RewriteRule ^portfolio$ portfolio.php [L]
RewriteRule ^reportage$ reportage.php [L]
```

By adding anchors (`^` and `$`) to the `RewriteRule` pattern it will now only match "portfolio" etc. *exactly* and also avoid a rewrite loop. The `L` flag ensures that no further rules will be processed in this pass.

Answer (score 0):

I changed name of my folders to not conflict RewriteRule 's
Ex. Have `reportageImages---> my .jpg here` now its `imagesR` - name doesn't matter but it was in conflict someway with that RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule reportage reportage.php
```

Now it works.

Comment: the accepted solution ( by w3dk) is much better. If reading this take his solution :)

Comment: Yes, renaming the folders to avoid a conflict is generally undesirable (and avoidable)... change the rules to avoid the conflict instead! :)

Comment: http://kabocweb.ayz.pl/ can I ask you to take a look, in reportage section it is getting ruined, I checked portfolio.php and it has same code as reportage.php but with different image dir and it's working correctly. Somehow reportage is trying to load everything from unexisting folder and I cannot make out why :I ?

Comment: I commented on your other comment (before you deleted it?)... you need to remove the `<base href="/MG/start">` element from that page (at the end of the head section). All relative links will be seen as relative to the `/MG/` folder (which I assume either does not exist anymore, or the document root already points to this subfolder - as mentioned in comments above ...?).

Comment: no way i missed that, was even checking because I remembered that I put it there... Sry and thanks, give me address would send beer :)